# Want to customize html of default page elements

Tags: visualforce, site.com

I am creating a menu using menu in Page Elements

When I add it to page it's HTML is like

```
<ul>
   <li class="pageHome">
      <a href="/Home">
         <span>Home</span>
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Is there any way so that I can remove `span` from it..
or if I have multiple `li`'s then adding a particular class to only last `li`?

I am new to site.com and have no idea how it can be done

Comment: Can you use jQuery?  That for sure can remove `span` tags or add a particular class to only the last `li` (via CSS selectors).

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** Just realised, though you tagged this as a VF question you may not be authoring VF pages yourself directly? Let me know and I'll remove this answer if so.

Yes the Visualforce components do like to output one or two spans along the way! For example apex:outputPanel. You can control span output via the 'layout' attribute, here is what the docs have to say regarding apex:outputPanel and the 'layout' attribute. Though you'll also find it on others.

> The layout style for the panel. Possible values include "block" (which generates an HTML div tag), "inline" (which generates an HTML span tag), and "none" (which does not generate an HTML tag). If not specified, this value defaults to "none". However, if layout is set to "none", for each child element with the rendered attribute set to "false", the outputPanel generates a span tag, with the ID of each child, and a style attribute set to "display:none". Thus, while the content is not visible, JavaScript can still access the elements through the DOM ID.

Hope this helps, if not please post some of your VF markup.

Comment: No I am not authoring VF pages myself...I am just using  site.com where i want menu items..but it displayed as above when i picked it from page elements to the left..i want to remove span from it..It can be done using custom code...but want to do it using elements given in site.com..sorry for the confusion :)